# Why are timestamps "allow null" when using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `t.timestamps` in migrations. The behavior should produce the following:

```
'created_at' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
'updated_at' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But instead what rails generates ends up being this in the MySQL db:

```
'created_at' datetime DEFAULT NULL
'updated_at' datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

Even though these fields will get auto-populated by rails, the actual database schema should be accurate as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `DEFAULT NOW()` at all, since it will default to the `NOW()` when this table was created and that's clearly not what you are looking for.

As for the `NOT NULL` piece, you can always send a PR to the Rails project and fix this or just create the timestamps manually instead of calling `t.timestamps`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`